# Arduino code for multiple buttons and LED matrix

Tags: button, arduino, arduino-uno, led

I'm trying to build a system using Arduino Uno, 8x8 LED matrix and 3 push buttons. The goal of the system is to display 3 different characters upon pushing the 3 buttons correspondingly. For instance, I've chosen the letters A,B,C. When the button corresponding to A is pressed, the letter A must be displayed and similar for B and C too. I'm kinda stuck in this code, where it seems logically correct for me but I have no idea why it isn't working. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "LedControlMS.h"
#define NBR_MTX 1
LedControl lc=LedControl(4,3,2, NBR_MTX);//
const int buttonPinA = 8;
const int buttonPinB = 9;
const int buttonPinC = 10;
char ip2;
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  for (int i=0; i< NBR_MTX; i++)
  {
    lc.shutdown(i,false);
    lc.setIntensity(i,8);
    lc.clearDisplay(i);
    delay(100);
  }
}
void Fun1()
{
              lc.writeString(0,"A");
              delay(500);
              lc.clearAll();
}
void Fun2{
          lc.writeString(0,"B");
              delay(500);
              lc.clearAll();
}
void Fun3()
{
              lc.writeString(0,"C");
              delay(500);
              lc.clearAll();
}
void loop(){

if( digitalRead(buttonPinA) == HIGH){
  ip2 = 1;}
else if(digitalRead(buttonPinB) == HIGH){
  ip2 = 2;}
else if(digitalRead(buttonPinC) == HIGH){
  ip2 = 3;
}
if(ip2 == '1'){
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
  Fun1();
  }
}
else if(ip2 == '2')
{
 for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
 Fun2();}
}
else if(ip2 == '3'){
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
Fun3();}
}}
```

Comment: I don't see any `main`. That should call `setup` and then call `loop`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Arduino internally handles it by calling setup once and loop repeatedly

Comment: Can you add a print to check if condition in "if( digitalRead(buttonPinA) == HIGH)" ever get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `char ip2` variable as an integer and then checking it as a character. You will see in this [ASCII Table](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/ASCII-Table-wide.svg/875px-ASCII-Table-wide.svg.png) that '1' is equal to 31 as in integer, '2' is equal to 32 and so on.

Replacing the first few lines of you main loop with the code below should fix your problem. If not, I would check the documentation of the led library you're using and make sure you're implementing it correctly.

```
if( digitalRead(buttonPinA) == HIGH)
{
    ip2 = '1';
}
else if(digitalRead(buttonPinB) == HIGH)
{
    ip2 = '2';
}
else if(digitalRead(buttonPinC) == HIGH)
{
    ip2 = '3';
}
```